# How to customize the size of frame Icon image?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating Swing frame demo.

I have set an image icon in the title bar of `JFrame`, and I know the default size of the icon is 16x16. How can I change the height and width of the icon?

Comment: imho, you can't, it is os (or more precisely, wm's) prerogative

Comment: it is either OS-dependent or PLAF-dependent (if your PLAF can decorate frames and you have called JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true) or same for JDialog). Besides, you can also provide better resolution icons (but you can't decide which one will be used) by using Window.setIconImages() API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame icon image size can't be changed.  If you need something really custom you will to create your own decorations for a window, but that is not as simple as just changing the size of an icon.